# What are the ways of making NFTs unique?

Tags: plutus, nft, plutus-pioneer-program, minting

In the week 5 of Plutus Pioneer Program Lars described how to make NFT by spending an UTxO while minting, therefore ensuring the uniqueness of the token.

Are there any other ways of making NFTs unique?

What if I wanted to create let's say, a collection of thousands of unique tokens. Creating as many UTxOs to refer to them further on would incur significant cost in the fees. Are there any cheaper/simpler ways to do it?

PS: Solutions not available in Plutus yet are also welcome as examples.

Comment: "What if I wanted to create let's say, a collection of thousands of unique tokens. Creating as many UTxOs to refer to them further on would incur significant cost in the fees."


Are you hoping to have many NFTs created in a single transaction? AFAIK tokens created from the same script will always have the same currency symbol. It might save on fees if you forge them all in one transaction but different scripts.

Answer (score 6):

NFTs have to be minted in some way or the other. In order to mint you will have to run a script with monetary policy for which you have to pay a fee, so might as well use that UTxO.

You can mint multiple NFTs in a single script though. Remember that a Value is identified by its CurrencySymbol and the TokenName. The CurrencySymbol is unique because of the UTxO input and is shared across all NFTs minted in the same contract. You can use a different TokenName for each NFT to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: I've been wondering about this. Are two tokens that share a currency symbol but have unique token names effectively as non-fungible as tokens with unique currency symbols?

Comment: I believe that is the case.

Comment: So, for example, if I wanted to represent land plot ownership by a NFT, I could mint as many of them as transaction size limit permits, spending a single UTxO. The plot ID would be included in the TokenName and people could trade those tokens freely but wouldn't be able to modify the plot ID within the tokens they own?